# How to fill combobox with text file item!

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a text file which contain following type item

```
wett45456,4556,45657,898

tyu5878,4566,7989,55565
```

now i have a windowform on that form ihave a combobox now i want fill combobox with firstitem of each row  `wett45456`,`tyu5878`

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines("Myfile.txt");
foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
{
   string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
   comboBox1.Items.Add(tokens[0]);
}
```

Comment: tokens should be checked that it contains a value.

Comment: @Dotnet How can we 'skip' empty lines between the two lines having data?

Answer (score 0):

It is another solution with Regular Expressions

```
        string txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file.txt");

        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[A-Za-z0-9]+");
        foreach(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in rx.Matches(txt))
        {
            If(m.Value.Trim().length>0)
                MyComboBox.Items.Add(m.Value);
        }
```